# Relation between ranks of free sheaves and cohomology

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, sheaf-cohomology

Suppose that $\mathbb{P}^r=\mathbb{P}^r_K$ is the projective space over a field $K$. Let 
$\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^r}(-1)^n\longrightarrow \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^r}^m$ be a morphism of vector bundles. How can I show that $$m\leq h^0(C)$$
where $C$ is the cokernel of the map and $h^0(-)=\dim_k H^0(-)$?

**Edit**

I realize that this seems not to hold, but then I can't understand why the following theorem doesn't fail. It's form Eisenbud's Geometry of Syzygies. 
[image]

Corollary 5.9 is the following:
[image]

A linear presentation for a graded finitely generated module $M$ over a polynomial ring $R$ is an exact sequence of the form
$$R(-1)^n\longrightarrow R^m\longrightarrow M\longrightarrow 0$$

Comment: If the superscripts indicate direct sums, then this is not a map of line bundles for $n>1$ or $m>1$. At any rate, there is always a surjection $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbf{P}_k^r}(-1)^{r+1}\to\mathscr{O}_{\mathbf{P}_K^r}$, as Jake Levinson indicates, in which case the cokernel $C$ is zero, so your inequality fails.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is true. For example, let $m = 1$; then there is a surjection $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^r}(-1)^{r+1} \to \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^r}$, i.e. the cokernel $C$ is the zero sheaf.

Comment: This is true, however please see the edit because there must be something I missed about.